# RxJava2 doOnNext returns later than intended

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

So I'm pretty sure that I'm kind of at a loss here.

The expected behavior is:

> Get data from API -> save it in the local DB -> load data from the
>   local DB and display it

First of all in my `Fragment` I call a function that does this:

```
mLiveData = viewModel.fetchAllCategories(getString(R.string.lang_code))
mCategoryLiveData!!.observe(this, Observer<Array<Category>> { it ->
            if (it != null) {
                this@CategoryListFragment.allCategories = SparseArray(it.size)
                for (category in it) {
                        allCategories[category.id] = category
                }   

                displayedCategory = allCategories[1]
                this@CategoryListFragment.mLoadingCircle.visibility = View.GONE
                this@CategoryListFragment.displayCategoryChildren()
            }
        })
```

fetchAllCategories calls a function in the ViewModel which calls this function:

```
fun getAllCategoriesFromAPI(language: String): Flowable<Array<Category>> {
    return service.getAllCategories(language)
        .doOnNext {
        Log.e("Repository", "Fetched ${it.size} Categories from the API ")                
        storeCategoriesInDb(it)
    }
}
```

However the function `displayCategoryChildren()` fires before the onNext finishes which results in an error since the data the app is supposed to get from the db is not saved there yet.

If it is in any way relevant I can also post the fuction in the `ViewModel`

Comment: **RxJava2 doOnNext finishes too late** It doesn't.

Comment: With given information all I can tell is that there is no guarantee that `doOnNext` block to complete before `LiveData` emits something. If possible, posting how `fetchAllCategories()` is connected to `getAllCategoriesFromAPI()` and how `storeCategoriesInDb()` is implemented should help people to answer.